# Attempted import error: 'FiMail' is not exported from 'react/icons/fa

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-icons

**It shows that there is some error while importing `FiMail` from react icon even after reinstalling the pack**

The Error:

> Attempted import error: 'FiMail' is not exported from 'react/icons/fa'

```
import { FiMail } from 'react-icons/fa'
import {
  HeroContainer,
  Socials
} from "./HeroElements";
const Hero = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <HeroContainer>
        <Socials>
              <FiMail />
        </Socials>
      </HeroContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Attempted import error: 'FiMail' is not exported from 'react/icons/fa

Comment: Go to the react/icons/fa in node_modules and check the export `FiMail`